# Focus+Context via Brushing for dual scaled zoomed chart in d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I've walked through the example [Focus+Context via Brushing chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) and couldn't figure out how to implement it for dual scaled zoomed chart. I've created focus and context elements, and trying to make them work together.
Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p29qC/5/). 
Coffeescript piece is below:

```
focus = canvas.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," +       margin.top + ")")

focus.append("svg:rect").attr("width", width).attr("height", height).attr("class", "plot")
clip = focus.append("svg:clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("svg:rect")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)


drawHorizontalAxis(focus, xAxis, width, height, "dates", "")
drawVerticalAxis(focus, yLeftAxis, "price", "")
drawRightVerticalAxis(focus, yRightAxis, width, "yoy", "")

chartBody = focus.append("g")
.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")

drawPathLine(chartBody, line1, data, "", "", "line1")
drawPathLine(chartBody, line2, data, "", "", "line2")

# make grid
focus.append("g")
.attr("class", "y grid")
.call(make_y_axis().tickSize(-width, 0, 0).tickFormat(""))


# --- Below chart --- #

# brush axis
xScale2 = d3.time.scale().range([0,width]).domain(d3.extent(data, (d) -> d.date))
xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom").ticks(5)

yScale2 = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, yLeftMax]).range([height2, 0])

brush = d3.svg.brush()
 .x(xScale2)
 .on("brush", brushed)

brushed = ->
  xScale.domain (if brush.empty() then xScale2.domain() else brush.extent())
  focus.select("._x._axis").call xAxis


context = canvas.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")")

context.append("g").attr("class", "_x _axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")").call xAxis2
context.append("g")
  .attr("class", "_x brush")
  .call(brushed)
.selectAll("rect")
  .attr("y", -6)
  .attr("height", height2 + 7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference when you're doing it with two y axes -- only the x axis changes. Your example was almost there, apart from the following things.

- You called `brushed` on the element that is supposed to "hold" the brush instead of `brush`.
- Your `brushed` function needs to be defined before you tell the brush to use it.
- You need to redraw the lines on brush, i.e.

  `canvas.select(".line1").attr("d", line1(data))
  canvas.select(".line2").attr("d", line2(data))`

Also, the zoom behaviour was interfering with the brush because it was active on the same elements. I've fixed the problems and disabled the zoom for demonstration purposes [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p29qC/6/).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Is there a way to make a zoom working along with brush by making them active on different elements?

Comment: Yes, like you say, you just have to make them active on different elements.